# How to not run next .then() functions if .catch() catched an error

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, fetch-api

```js
const getWeather = () => {
  fetch('http://localhost:3000/api/v1/weather?location=' + weatherLocation.value)
    .then(res => {
      if (res.ok) return res.json();
      else throw new Error(res.status + ' (' + res.statusText + ')');
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log('[SERVER] Could not get weather information');
      console.log(err);
    })
    .then(data => updateWeather(data.data))
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
};
```

The last `.then()` function should not run if the first `.catch()` function catched an error?

As of right now, the `data` parameter in the last`.then()` function is `undefined` because the request failed. The second `.catch()` does catch that error but it should have never run in the first place.

How can I do this?

Comment: You need to `throw err` in the first catch, otherwise it creates a _resolved_ promise.

Comment: Uh, don't `.catch()` the error if you don't want to handle it?